# How to change color of Search Icon as hint

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-imageview, android-toolbar, android-icons

In my mobile the color of search icon is showing in Grey color.

[image]

I have tried following code to change it to White but nothing happened:

```
int magId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_mag_icon", null, null);
            ImageView searchhintIcon = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(magId);
            if (null != searchhintIcon) {
                searchhintIcon.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
            }
```

How can I change this search hint icon color to White?

Here is my themes.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionModeBackground">@color/cometchat_grey</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">#5477B1</item>
        <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: try my answer. let me know is it work for you?

Comment: What is the actual color of your icon?

Comment: @DaminiMehra I will let you know

Comment: @FaisalShaikh ok check it

Answer (score 0):

try this answer:

there is no easy way to change the SearchView icon to a custom drawable, since the theme attribute searchView Search Icon is not public.

However, I think that your problem is caused by inheriting from the wrong theme. Please use android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar as the base for your theme. Then the default icons on the action bar should have a light color

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
...
</style>
```

Comment: I have tried your solution but still facing this issue. FYI i am facing this issue in android 4.4.4 and lower api levels. Above Kitkat its showing the icon in white color. Also I have tried changing the icon in the main app theme but still no help.

Comment: We have added themes.xml file, kindly check

Comment: I have the same problem in Kitkat. But it's fine in Marshmallow. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
 private void setColor(ImageView imageView) {
        int color = Color.parseColor("#EE3A8C");
        imageView.setColorFilter(color);
    }

    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    setColor(image);
```

Comment: This is not for what I am looking for. while initialize `image` object how do I know the `id` of `overflow menu icon`?